# Change log levels in netflix conductor (java springboot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, netflix-conductor

Is there a way to change the log level from error to warn in Workflow Task Coordinator of Netflix Conductor.

PS: I'm using Java SpringBoot

```
for (Task task : tasks) {
            try {
                executorService.submit(() -> {
                    try {
                        logger.debug("Executing task {}, taskId - {} in worker - {}", task.getTaskDefName(), task.getTaskId(), worker.getIdentity());
                        execute(worker, task);
                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                        task.setStatus(Task.Status.FAILED);
                        TaskResult result = new TaskResult(task);
                        handleException(t, result, worker, task);
                    }
                });
            } catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {
                WorkflowTaskMetrics.incrementTaskExecutionQueueFullCount(worker.getTaskDefName());
                logger.error("Execution queue is full, returning task: {}", task.getTaskId(), e);
                returnTask(worker, task);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

We can put below line to the application.properties for the worker.

```
logging.level.package.class=WARN
```

where package.class is absolute class name along with package name.
If there is no code changes then below is the exact configuration,

```
logging.level.com.netflix.conductor.client.automator.TaskPollExecutor=WARN
```